# Restrict the expansion of search for cts:element-value-search- Marklogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am using cts:element-value-search to search document based on the parameter. While the query works fine I want it to search elements in immediate children only.

For Ex. My document tree looks like this

document1.xml

```
<Person>
    <FirstName>Johnson</FirstName>
    <LastName>W</LastName>
    <EmailAddress>john@abc.com</EmailAddress>
    <Neighbour>
        <FirstName>Mathew</FirstName>
        <LastName>Long</LastName>
    </Neighbour>
</Person>
```

document2.xml

```
<Person>
    <FirstName>Mathew</FirstName>
    <LastName>W</LastName>
    <EmailAddress>john@abc.com</EmailAddress>
    <Neighbour>
        <FirstName>Anderson</FirstName>
        <LastName>Long</LastName>
    </Neighbour>
</Person>
```

and my query is

```
cts:search(
  /Person,
  cts:and-query((
      cts:element-value-query(xs:QName("FirstName"), concat('*', "son", '*'), 
        ("wildcarded", "case-insensitive", "whitespace-sensitive", "punctuation-sensitive"))
  )),
  ()
)
```

This returns both the documents because for the first document it matches `<FirstName>Johnson</FirstName>`

and for the second document it matches

```
<FirstName>Anderson</FirstName>
```

which is at the lower level.

I do not want the second result and want the query to search at level 1 only.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can scope sub-queries to particular container elements or properties, using `cts:element-query`, and `cts:json-property-scope-query`. Those will trim down sub-query matches to a particular ancestor.

`cts:element-query(xs:QName('Person'), cts:element-value-query(xs:QName('Firstname', ...))` will not be enough however, as `Neighbour/Firstname` is also a descendant.

Simplest option is to use a path range index on `Person/Firstname`. That is by far the most straight-forward solution here.

HTH!

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this using cts:element-value-query only? Because the above query is a part of entire query. I tried **lexicon-expansion-limit=1** option mentioned in marklogic [document](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:element-value-query) but it gives error saying invalid option.

Comment: A path range query really is the simplest way out. If you have the option to add such an index, then do. If that is no option, consider looking into `cts:not-in-query`.